# Run-time error when using vectors to convert given expression into polish notation

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

My program aim is to convert given mathematical expression into polish notation.
Mathematical expression is stored in vectors and recursion is used.

I am getting run time error when compiling it.
Using debugger it shows segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

It is assumed that input is of the form (a+b) and corresponding output should be ab+.  (brackets mandatory)

Actually it is [this problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/) of SPOJ.

My approach is as follows -

Use vectors to store expression

If expression size is greater than 1

then remove brackets which are always present at end of string using pop_back and vector::erase .

divide the vector into three parts - string 1 , operator and string 2 (string 1 and string 2 are vectors )

simplify vectors string 1 and string 2 to their polish notation using recursion

Clear original vector passed to function and add string 1 , operator and string 2 to it.

change() is used to accomplish all these things

Here is my program which converts a single statement to it's polish notation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void convert(std::vector <char> &vect)
{

  if(vect.size()!=1&&vect.size()!=0)
  {
    vect.pop_back();
    vect.erase(vect.begin());
    std::vector<char> str1;
    std::vector<char> str2;
    char op;

    int i=0;
    int reqcount = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(vect[i]=='(')
            reqcount++ ;

        if(vect[i]==')')
            reqcount-- ;

        str1.push_back(vect[i]);

        if(!reqcount)
            break;

        i++;

    }

    op=vect[i];

    while((i+1)!=vect.size())
    {
        str2.push_back(vect[i+1]);
        i++;
    }

    vect.clear();
    convert(str1);
    convert(str2);


    for(int i=0; i<str1.size(); i++ )
    {
        vect.push_back(str1[i]);
    }

    vect.push_back(op);

    for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++)
    {
        vect.push_back(str2[i]);
    }
  }

}

int main( void )
{
std::vector<char> testinput;;
char c;
std::cin>>std::noskipws;
while(std::cin>>c&&c!='\n')
testinput.push_back(c);
convert(testinput);
for(int i=0;i<testinput.size();i++)
std::cout<<testinput[i];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"...I am getting segmentation error when compiling it.(SIGSEGV)..."_ no you are getting a runtime error, use your debugger to find it.

Comment: You forgot to handle the empty `vect`.

Comment: Sorry.Changed segmentation error to run-time error.

Comment: Included the case of empty vect but i don't think that case will ever come when vect is empty except when input is empty .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with `int i = 0` which will point to the overall brackets (). It will read the entire string as str1 minus the closing ')'. op will be ')' if I'm not mistaking and str2 will remain empty.

Then you recursively call 'convert(str1)' which doesn't have a closing braket so you'll try to go past the end of the array and get your SIGSEGV.

Make sure your split works correctly and double-check the boundary conditions to prevent it.

P.S. Your solution is O(N^2). You can do O(N).

Comment: Actually if brackets are removed from the expression then then i think spliting will work fine.

Comment: Suppose expression is (a+b). After removing brackets it will be a + b . Loop will stop after inserting a in string 1.

Comment: Actually i don't really no how to debug program using debugger . But after trying i it appears that brackets at end are not getting removed properly thus leading to problem you mentioned .

Comment: Well . You were right that my spliting was wrong. I was incrementing the value of i at the wrong place. It should be incremented before encountering break . Otherwise string 2 will end up with only closing bracket if input is ( a+b ) leading to the error . Thanks .